# How could stalk functor be seen as the pullback functor for the morphism $i_x:\{x\}\to X$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory, slice-category

In the stacks project website, the proof of lemma 6.27.3,
https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0099
, it claims that the stalk functor $[-]_x:\mathscr{F}\mapsto \mathscr{F}_x$ could be seen as the pullback functor for the inclusion morphism $i_x:\{x\}\to X$ between topological spaces (where $x$ is a point in X), which means

[image]

I am confused about this claim. Firstly, the slice category $\mathbf{Top}/X$ consists of morphisms (continuous maps)$Y\to X$, so could each such topological space $Y$ be seen as a sheaf over $X$?

Comment: Do you understand the claim when we're dealing with sheaves of abelian groups and the stalk and pullback functor are defined via direct limits?

Comment: @KReiser Actually I even do not understand the claim when we're dealing with sheaves of abelian groups. I knew the the stalk and pullback functor are defined via direct limits, however, I still could not realize how the relation between sheaves and topological spaces here.

Comment: You say that you're confused by the business of identifying categories of sheaves with slice categories of continuous maps to the base, but I don't see this mentioned on the linked page of [Stacks]; from where are you getting this? In any case, I would assume this is in reference to the étalé space of the sheaf, but one needs to be a bit careful (maybe restricting to local homeomorphisms is enough?)

Comment: @TabesBridges I assume categories of sheaves and slice categories should be isomorphism, since functors $i_x^*$ and $[-]_x$ could be seen as same by the claim. Do you know the other way to explain the claim 'the stalk functor could be seen as the pullback functor for the inclusion morphism $i_x:\{x\}\to X$'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any continuous morphism of topological spaces $f: Y \to X$, we define the pullback $f^*\mathcal{F}$ of a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ to be
$$f^*\mathcal{F}(U)= \mathrm{colim}_{f(U)\subset V} \mathcal{F}(V)$$
Where $U$ is an open subset of $Y$ and $V$ is an open subset of $X$. If you apply this to the special case $Y=\left \{ x \right \}$ and $f=i_x$ is the inclusion. Then the definition above is reduced to
$$i_x^*\mathcal{F}(\left \{ x \right \}) = \mathrm{colim}_{ x \in V} \mathcal{F}(V) = \mathcal{F}_x.$$
The notation $\mathbf{Top}/X$ indicates the cateogory of sheaves on $X$, not the slice category.

Comment: So the 'pullback functor' here is not the general meaning of pullback functor between slice categories? And the meaning of 'pullback' here is similar to the pullback functor of vector bundles $\mathbf{Vec}(X)\to \mathbf{Vec}(Y)$ induced by $f:Y\to X$?